# jQuery MatchHeight performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use jQuery [matchHeight](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). It's used to make all elements in a row the same height.

I have a page with a lot of elements and it is very slow to load and also if you resize the browser (that fire the matchHeight update) you have to wait the finish of the function.

[Here](https://embed.plnkr.co/4Wny1oLlD0nSCZ58s9Ma/) you can find an example (open it in fullscreen).

As you can see I include Bootstrap (Css on  and jScript on the end of page), jQuery, the plugin MatchHeight and in my script.js I initialize it with this code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

  // matchHeight
  $(function() {
      $('.col-eq-height').matchHeight({
          property: 'min-height'
      });
  });

});
```

The page contain a lot of elements with class "col-eq-height" where I apply the matchHeight functionality.

How can I increase the performance of this plugin?

For example applying the matchHeight only for the showing elements (based by scroll position) and not for all elements on each browser window resize.

Thanks and sorry for my English

Comment: You would have to dive deeper and be more specific. The answer to your question can be Yes, or No, but it won't help you neither other visitors.

Comment: I'm asking for a solution for the problem. If anyone could help me, I think other developers that use this plugin will be greatful

Comment: Considering that the Plunker crashes and/or takes way too long to load, I'd suggest you first try to optimise your web page, probably through lazy loading. Also, instead of match height with JS, you might be interested in CSS3's flex.

Comment: Thank you. The page take long to load because of the plugin. In my production project I use infinite scroll to load the elements (so the loading problem is solved), but when a lot of them are loaded if the user resize the window, the browser "block" and the user wait for unblock. I made the page in Plunker for testing the problem. I don't know CSS3 Flex. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is pretty much a non-answer, because you've asked what I'd pretty much consider a non-question. Nobody is going to write extensive code like that for you, especially not with such an arbitrary question as "can you make this faster?". You have also provided no attempts at what you've tried to do.

Honestly, basically anything can have its performance increased. If you're asking for somebody to test and develop something that's fast for your particular use case, then you'd better check your bank balance and hire yourself a professional. That can be a very challenging task, depending on what "fast" means to you. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript) a list of the very basics about optimizing JavaScript.

Also, for the love of God please could you be more specific in your questions than

> where I apply the matchHeight functionality.

That doesn't help people to understand what it is you're trying to achieve. What's the context, i.e., what kind of page are you designing here? Maybe then the question would not be "improve the plugin's performance", but instead, "what other designs/methods of design can I use that don't have such massive performance penalties?".

If you want a list of items displayed and there are **hundreds**, why not paginate them, like Google does? Or an infinite scroll?

Also, if it's element positioning you're after, why not attempt to calculate exactly what type of layout you want first, then use CSS? I've never had to use jQuery for non-animated HTML design, and I'm increasingly using CSS for animations, too. Maybe you should reconsider exactly what type of layout you are after and try to use CSS first. JavaScript is going to be CPU expensive if you're playing with thousands of elements' styling.

**EDIT**: As per the comments, if the question is rephrased to "how can I make the child elements of a row the same height as the row", we could do the following:

```css
.container {
    display: table;
}
.child {
    width: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
        a<br />a<br />a
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content">
            a<br />a<br />a
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, you can see that the elements are all the same height, without needing `flexbox` (which is still occasionally unsupported). Hope that helps.

Comment: We'd need to know more about the problem you're trying to solve. What layout would you like, and what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm sorry if the question is unclear. I was hoping that someone had already have this problem with this jQuery plugin and could help me. Maybe this plugin is not useful for my scope. Sorry. I'll try something else (maybe the CSS flex or other)

Comment: I'm trying to layout a list of hundreds elements (responsive) in row where every row's height is calculated in base of the elements content (on the same row). I found the mathHeight jQuery plugin but with many elements I see it will block the browser for some seconds. So my question was if there is a way to increase the performance of this plugin.

edit: [link]http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/ the demo version of the matchHeight plugin is what I'm looking, but with many elements it is "slow"

Comment: No worries, sorry if any SO answer's tone seems pissy sometimes, I forget how it comes across to new question askers. Sometimes can be too direct to answer the question quickly, so it might sound snappy! Sure, flexbox sounds like a good example. Do you want each div to fill the height of its containing row completely?

Comment: Yes. As @Bram say I'm looking for the Flex property. It seems it is the correct way.

Comment: Thank you. It is a valid alternative. I'll work on it.